# NSOpenPanel - Everything deprecated?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I've been trying to get a window to show up asking the person to choose a file, and I eventually did. The problem is, Xcode complains that the method I'm using is deprecated. I looked in the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but everything under the "running panels" section has been deprecated as of Mac OS 10.6. Is there a different class I'm supposed to be using now?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the `runModal` method like shown below:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];

if ([openPanel runModal] == NSOKButton)
{
    NSString *selectedFileName = [openPanel filename];
}
```

Comment: @Cole The reason you couldn't find this method is because it is implemented by `NSSavePanel`, which is `NSOpenPanel`'s superclass. +1

Comment: The same is true of the other, better ways of running a save or open panel, including the method for running one as a sheet.

Comment: In Xcode, alt-clicking `filename` in this code tells me that `[openPanel filename]` is deprecated as of 10.6.  The replacement is `[openPanel URLs]` (as used in Guillaume's answer).

Comment: NSOKButton is deprecated: replace with NSModalResponseOK.

Answer (score 30):

In 10.6, there was a few changes to this classes. One of the benefits is that there is now a block-based API.

Here is a code snippet on how to use that:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [[NSOpenPanel openPanel] retain];

// Configure your panel the way you want it
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"txt"]];

[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

        for (NSURL *fileURL in [panel URLs]) {
            // Do what you want with fileURL
            // ...
        }
    }

    [panel release];
}];
```

Comment: This looks like it's the correct code to use under 10.10, but get rid of the retain and release bits if you're using ARC.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [- beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:) if you don't want a separate open dialog.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing how I found this question useful six years later, and since there are no swift answers, here's a swift solution.

You'll find two samples, one as a stand alone window and the other as a sheet.

**Swift 3.0**

```
func selectIcon() {
    // create panel
    let panel = NSOpenPanel()

    // configure as desired
    panel.canChooseFiles = true
    panel.canChooseDirectories = false
    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    panel.allowedFileTypes = ["png"]

    // *** ONLY USE ONE OF THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS, NOT BOTH ***

    // ********************** OPTION 1 ***********************
    // use this if you want a selection window to display that is
    // displayed as a separate stand alone window
    panel.begin { [weak self] (result) in
        guard result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton, panel.urls.isEmpty == false, let url = panel.urls.first else {
            return
        }

        let image = NSImage.init(contentsOf: url)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.iconImageView.image = image
        }
    }

    // ********************** OPTION 2 ***********************        
    // use this if you want a sheet style view that displays sliding
    // down from your apps window
    panel.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!) { [weak self] (result) in
        guard result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton, panel.urls.isEmpty == false, let url = panel.urls.first else {
            return
        }

        let image = NSImage.init(contentsOf: url)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.iconImageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the `.begin` is a completion handler. For future on-lookers: You can also do: `let response = panel.runModal();if response == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {/*do things with panel.url*/}` Also works for `.CANCEL`